# How to check NIC is created before creating machine in terraform script

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am running Jenkins jobs to create a Azure instance and that will run terraform script to do this task.The terraform script will create NIC first and later it will create VM.Sometimes the NIC creation is taking too long in Azure environment and Vm creation steps are getting  executed before NIC fully created.Is there any way so that Script should go to next step only when NIC creation is done fully.Can someone help?

Comment: is there a reason you aren't creating the network interface in the same config file as the virtual machine?  If you do that you can reference the resource id of the network interface and it will wait until it is done to start the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is define the NIC as an explicit dependency on the VM in the Terraform.  There are odd cases when you have to do it that way. So on the VM you just need to add the depends on property and the resource. If the resource is created outside of terraform you may have to use a datasource to load it in.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name = "${var.prefix}-vm"

  depends_on = [azurerm_network_interface.main]
}
```

The docs:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#depends_on-explicit-resource-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your reply.We have already added depends_on property in script.As there is a dependency on NIC ,I don't want to execute until NIC created.VM creation step should execute only NIC is created properly..Any suggestion ??

Comment: If you are doing this all with terraform then it will automatically wait for the the NIC to be completed. Are you running two separate terraform scripts? Can you combine them?

Comment: I am running a terraform script file which contains NIC resource ,Vhd and Vm resource.and Vm resource is depends on NIC..I am not facing issue everytime.But sometime i can see the jenkin jobs are failing with the error that the vm creation steps failed due to no existance of nic..Terraform version is 0.11 ,Azure provider version is 1.25.0 and terraform random provider 2.2 .1..Any suggestion in this case??